# ER-Diagram: Can an ENTITY be an ATTRIBUTE to ANOTHER ENTITY?

Tags: database, entity-relationship

I have an entity called *Employee*. One of the attributes of employee can be his/her *designation* .

I have made the Designation also as an entity . Its **attributes** could be desg_ID and Design_name.

So my question is, can Designation be an entity and an attribute for the same ER model. Or is it conceptually wrong.

If you think Designation is should not be considered as an entity but only an attribute, please suggest so as well.

Thank You :)

Comment: You **need** to **lay** off **writing** like **this**.

Comment: Sorry. I think it makes the question more readable. If it really bugs people, i will not use it :)

Comment: @Shruti Just use it with care and try to use more types of formatting based on what you're trying to highlight. For example, code or value things like `desg_ID` or `Design_name` could be formatted as code.

Comment: @Mario ahh.. this makes sense. I will keep this in mind.  Thank You! ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### May an attribute be an entity as well?

This sounds really confusing, but I'd say that's not possible. However, you could have an attribute referencing a specific entity.

#### Should a "Designation" be its own entity?

IMO this really depends on how it's handled or what you consider a "Designation". If there's a strict 1:1 relation between an *Employee* and a *Designation*, then it's quite obsolete and it could be part of the actual *Employee*. If it's possible to have more than one *Designation* and/or a *Designation* might be reassigned/moved/swapped, then yes, it should be its own entity IMO.

Comment: I dont understand if its a YES or a NO. `designation` can hav one to many relationship with `employee`- meaning many employees can have one  same designation say 'Assistant'. In that case should i make `designation` an entity in itself and an attribute of `employee` entity? Or does it seem unnecessary ?

Comment: Correct. If it's a 1:* or *:* then you'll definitely want it to be its own entity that's only referenced. Just think for yourself: *"If I'd like to rename the designation, I don't want to edit it multiple times."* -> Entity of its own.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds a bit like you are normalizing your model. If you think `Designation` can be its own table then, conceptually, it should be considered a building block in your model.

I think the other part of you question relates to foreign keys (FK). Yes, your `Employee` entity can have a Designation ID FK, for example.